# How should a System.Decimal be converted to BigEndian format for sending to a bigendian server?

Tags: c#, .net

IIUC the System.Decimal representation is an array of 32bit words in this order:

```
lo mid hi flags
```

From a little endian representation, to serialise for a System.Decimal recipient on a big endian server, is it necessary to:

1. Preserve lo mid and hi order
2. Reverse the bytes in each lo/mid/hi integer
3. Preserve the flags integer byte ordering

I guess this means using `GetBits` to get the words , reverse each integer apart from the 4th element, and re-assemble the bytes to send to the server?

Comment: The following may be helpful: [BitConverter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter?view=net-6.0)

Comment: It is not a sensible question.  System.Decimal uses a binary format that is not standardized, beyond the original OLE Automation specification.  That server needs to boot Windows or use .NET Core to have a shot at interpreting the serialized value correctly.  Currently there is no big-endian flavor of either.  Consider a textual format, like JSON.

Comment: @HansPassant I am implementing a compiler that needs to work with direct binary representation of Decimal as it would appear on a bigendian architecture.... But yes the question is a bit dumb really as I now see from the source that the flags word in bits[3] is just treated as an integer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Decimal(int[])` [constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.-ctor?view=net-6.0#system-decimal-ctor(system-int32())) is documented as expecting the integers in a specific order,

```
bits is a four-element long array of 32-bit signed integers.

bits [0], bits [1], and bits [2] contain the low, middle, and high 32 bits of the 96-bit integer number.

bits [3] contains the scale factor and sign
```

which wouldn't change on an BigEndian platform.

If the Decimal is layed out in memory differently, that's handled internally.

Of course you may need to convert the Int32's to BigEndian if you're not using a standard framework like [protocol buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/) or json.

Comment: ok (many) thanks however I suppose my question is more specific: is the ints[3] flags a big endian int or just a byte array representation

Comment: actually no my question is stupid :-) bits[3] is an int

Comment: this is what c19 does to your mind